# Angular 2+ data bind without @Input

Tags: angular, data-binding

### Context

As we want to keep templates as simple as possible, a component is declared with identifiers, and data is retrieved from services, without explicit data binding.

```
<my-awesome-input field="makeDescription" displayItem maxLength="100" size="42" />
```

All components are derived from a `BaseComponent`, which has a value field with nice getter and setter :

```
get value(): any {
    return this.contentService.getItemData(this.block, this.field, this.computedIndex);
}

set value(value: any) {
    this.contentService.setItemData(this.block, this.field, this.id, value, this.computedIndex);
}
```

We also have a lot of properties for each component, that has to be set depending of other properties. Those properties may be used for displaying the component (CSS classes, tooltip, ...).

Problem is, as we are not using standard data binding, ngOnChanges is not triggered when a computed property value change.

As this is technical code and the programmer will only have to reuse the provided components, we can heavily customize these components.

### Solution #1

We might implement a custom change detector like this :

```
ngDoCheck() {
    const changes: SimpleChanges = {};
    let change = false;
    this.getFieldsToCheck().forEach(field => {
        const v = this[field];
        if (!this.firstChanges[field]) {
            changes[field] = new SimpleChange(undefined, v, true);
            this.firstChanges[field] = true;
            this.previousValues[field] = v;
            change = true;
        } else {
            const pv = this.previousValues[field];
            if (v !== pv) {
                changes[field] = new SimpleChange(pv, v, false);
                this.previousValues[field] = v;
                change = true;
            }
        }
    });
    if (change) {
        this.ngOnChanges(changes);
    }
}
```

It might be betterly done, but it works as expected. It is almost the same behaviour as standard @Input and ngOnChanges. Also, it might be slower than the standard change detector.

### Solution #2

We might encapsulate an inner component inside each provided component, with standard data binding with [(ngModel)] or [myattribute].

I've not tried this solution as it doesn't look nice, but it would reuse standard mechanisms.

### Other solutions, misunderstanding?

I'm pretty new in Angular 2+ development, and I may have missed something for a simpler solution.

I'm eager of any pointer for that kind of problem, or any opinion on purposed solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered all the options in [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular/10836/sharing-data-among-components#t=201707271007248314573)?

Comment: For me is unclear why you wouldn't you use @Input?

Comment: I would like to apply "DRY pattern", otherwise templates would look like `<my-awesome-input id="vehicle:{{currentIndexes.vehicle}}:modelDescription" displayItem maxLength="50" size="42" (modified)="checkModified($event)" (focused)="checkFocus($event)" [value]="getItemLovData(modelLov.selectedData.description,'vehicle','modelDescription')"></my-awesome-input>`!